# Helm: select n-th item

Tags: helm

In Helm I can see something like that:

```
Bibtex entries:
  2 Title of my first article
  3 Title of other article
  4 Title of still another article
```

How could I directly select (but not execute the default action) one entry by it's "line" number? (like number 4 here) I tried to look at the documentation, but can't find anything. The binding I found execute the line, and they are relatif, not absolute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `M-4 C-n/C-p`, the same as in ordinary buffers, the line numbers (expect the current line) are offsets.

There is a package for this purpose: https://github.com/cute-jumper/ace-jump-helm-line, though I've not tried it.

Comment: Hum, there is one problem: the line number I have are not offset but absolute value, and even if I'm on the first entry (line 2), I need no substract always 2 to the actual line I want to go to the good position (it's configured by `global-display-line-numbers-mode`). But the `ace-jump-helm-line` is great, thanks a lot!

Comment: @tobiasBora I don't use global-display-line-numbers-mode, I enable the line number in helm via `C-c l` (`helm-display-line-numbers-mode`), this command uses relative number, and you still can switch to relative number via `C-c l`.